# If statement outputting same every time no matter what the user input

Tags: php, mysql

I want to echo a field from database **IF** two other fields that are entered are correct with their corresponding ones in the database.
*example*

**Email:** (enters email: (is it same as one in database))

**Answer:** (enters answer: (is it the same as one matching email in database?))

**Code Echos....** Your password is here: (**********).

No matter the input on my code though, it always returns message ' Security Answer Correct' but then does not echo the variable.

**PhP Code**

```
$query = mysqli_query ($db, "SELECT * FROM admin where email = '$email' AND securitya = '$securitya'");

$password = mysqli_query ($db, "SELECT password FROM admin WHERE email = '$email' AND securitya = '$securitya'");
$passwordrow= mysqli_fetch_array ($password);
$result_password = $passwordrow ['password'];


$row = mysqli_fetch_array ($query);
if($row['email'] = $email AND $row['securitya'] = $securitya)
{

    $_SESSION['email'] = $row['securitya'];

    echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
    window.alert('Security Answer Correct');

    </SCRIPT>");
    echo ('<br>Password: ' . $result_password . '<br>');

}

else
{

die ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
    window.alert('Incorrect Security Answer, Please Try Again')
    window.location.href='passwordreset.php';
    </SCRIPT>");
} 

}
```

And I receive the error message:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: result_password in C:\xampp\htdocs\Intranet\passwordreset.php on line 118
```

What is Wrong with my statements is the question I am trying to ask.
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

Try with this code, I think this happens due to multiple query with same object.

```
$query = mysqli_query ($db, "SELECT * FROM admin where email = '$email' AND securitya = '$securitya'");

$row = mysqli_fetch_array ($query);
if($row['email'] == $email AND $row['securitya'] == $securitya)
{

    $_SESSION['email'] = $row['securitya'];

    echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
    window.alert('Security Answer Correct');

    </SCRIPT>");
    echo ('<br>Password: ' . $row['password'] . '<br>');

}

else
{

die ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
    window.alert('Incorrect Security Answer, Please Try Again')
    window.location.href='passwordreset.php';
    </SCRIPT>");
} 

}
```

Comment: `=` is not equal to `==`

Comment: Just tried that code and now it only outputs the 'correct' message no matter what the input, but also now have two notice messages:  Undefined index: password  AND Undefined variable: result_password

Comment: I have edited a piece of code, you need to remove the occurrences of $result_password from your code :)

Comment: can you dump your row data here so that you will get perfect answer

Comment: I forgot to add another few lines i have at the bottom of my code which is : SignIn();{

echo ('<br>Password: ' . $result_password . '<br>');
 
}
}   - and all the script above was the 'function SignIn' and now I have removed the Sign in from the bottom and used your code there is no output at all and no error messages

Comment: http://pastebin.com/ST1yN3pG Here is a  pastebin link to my full page of code... p.s. i know my code is really messy and unorganised at the moment im going to clean it up at a later date

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the values in the line below (which is triggering a false positive for the `if`), instead of comparing them.

```
if($row['email'] = $email AND $row['securitya'] = $securitya)
```

Use `==`  to compare:

```
if($row['email'] == $email AND $row['securitya'] == $securitya)
```

Comment: this still returns 'invalid' message

Answer (score 1):

Your query might be failing, use the debugging functions available, add `or die(mysqli_error($db));` after your queries to see if they're failing or not.

**Edit 1**

Seeing as you are using `MySQLi` you should use prepared statements to prevent `SQL` injections.

**Edit 2**

You are assigning values instead of comparing values, use `==` not `=` in your `if` statements.

**Edit 3**

Never trust user input, you should always sanitize all your input. Check out `htmlspecialchars`, `intval`, `trim` (not sanitizing but can be used to check for empty fields).

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra space as typo.

Replace this    `$result_password = $passwordrow ['password'];`

with this
`$result_password = $passwordrow['password'];`

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
if($row['email'] = $email AND $row['securitya'] = $securitya)
```

with

```
if($row['email'] == $email && $row['securitya'] == $securitya)
```

Comment: Have you used `&&` instead of `AND`